# CEFR-based assessment rubrics

Tags: cefr, student-evaluation

Regarding action-oriented scenarios, I do not know how to create an analytic grid/rubric (that is, a six/five-point Likert rating scale) calibrating CEFR descriptors of the same level, say B1 (specifically from competences and strategies).

Therefore, I’d appreciate it if you could offer some suggestions.

Comment: CEFR is used as a metalanguage to talk about knowledge/competence. It is not really a teaching aid. And I don't see "action" as a key work in it: https://rm.coe.int/common-european-framework-of-reference-for-languages-learning-teaching/16809ea0d4